# How to fix 'Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGADBannerView" was not found in the UIManager'?

Tags: ios, react-native, ads

Recently I tried to add react-native-admob to my app.
I got an error while working on ios.
    Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGADBannerView" was not found in the UIManager.

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
```

I added this to podfile.
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
And then, install pod again.
    cd ios
    pod install

I also added GADApplicationIdentifier to info.

```
import {
    AdMobBanner,
  } from 'react-native-admob'


class BannerAds extends Component {

    render() {
    return (

        <AdMobBanner
            style={styles.bottomBanner}
            adSize="banner"
            adUnitID="my app id"
            onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
        />
        // <View>

        // </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to recommend others to use the latest version of React, React Native, and react-native-admob.

In recent versions, all packages support autolinking.

This really helps us to use packages easily.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like `react-native-admob` package doesn't support autolinking (introduced in React Native 0.60) - it's still necessary to link it manually:

```sh
react-native link react-native-admob
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is still useful but
i installed the library again

1. run this command to unlink if it's linked, remember react native auto-linking is working fine
   `npx react-native unlink react-native-admob`
2. remove the library from the project
   `npm unlink react-native-admob -S`
3. run pod install
   `npx pod-install` OR `cd ios && pod install`
4. install the library again
   `npm i react-native-admob -S` OR `yarn react-native-admob`
5. after installation complete, open ios/Podfile file and add the following
   `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.69.0'`
6. run pod install

that should solve it.